# Modify Shipping Dimensions in WooCommerce Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to modifying Shipping Dimensions in a WooCommerce Cart based on meta data. I need help getting this to work. The meta data is coming from a WooCommerce plugin called TM Global Product Options.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'modify_cart', 10, 1);
function modify_cart( $cart_object ) {

    if ( (is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || $cart_object->is_empty() )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        $data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_tmcartepo_data'); 

        $cart_item['data']->set_width( $data['shipping_width'] );
        $cart_item['data']->set_height( $data['shipping_width'] );
        $cart_item['data']->set_length( $data['shipping_length'] );

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question or the problem? do you really get the data with `$data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_tmcartepo_data');` and have you tried to add `print_r($data);` to see if it's outputting something?

Comment: thanks for the guidance. i'll test that now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the exact same thing. WooCommerce holds the changes to the product inside a property called "changes." In order to apply them you must run the "apply_changes" method on the cart item. I modified your code below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'modify_cart', 10, 1);
function modify_cart( $cart_object ) {

    if ( (is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || $cart_object->is_empty() )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        $data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_tmcartepo_data'); 

        $cart_item['data']->set_width( $data['shipping_width'] );
        $cart_item['data']->set_height( $data['shipping_width'] );
        $cart_item['data']->set_length( $data['shipping_length'] );

        if( !empty( $cart_item['data']->get_changes() ) )
           $cart_item['data']->apply_changes();

    }
}
```